# Issue when I export as pdf single pages a spread in design doc

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I have an issue with the sigle pages PDF created from Indesign from a long document created as side-by-side pages (spread). I have a black background graphics on the right page and a blank page on the left. The exported PDF files shows a small part of the black background on the blank page even if in the document the background is not extended to the page on the left. 
Do you know how to solve this issue? I also have a 5mm bleed margin but I don’t think this should be a Problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an issue. It's a normal behavior if you set an equal bleed for each side. 
Your printer will handle this during the imposition process.

Now, if it really bothers you, you can set inside bleed to 0 in the document setup:  (unless you intend to print with wire-bound)

[image]

Comment: +1 Your'e absolutely right. But *maybe* you should stress that the bleed is *required* if the piece is being sent to press as single pages.